# AlwaysOn AG - Readable Secondary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

In the below window to configure an Always On Availability Group secondary, in the "Readable Secondary" column, what's the difference between `"Readable Secondary" = 'Yes'` and `'Read-intent only'`?

[image]

Comment: I think more context is needed. What database (and version) are you referring to? Have you tried checking the docs? What do they say that you don't fully understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-access-on-an-availability-replica-sql-server):

**Read-intent only**

> **Only read-only connections** are allowed to secondary databases of this replica.
>  The secondary database(s) are all available for read access.

**Yes**

> **All connections** are allowed to secondary databases of this replica, but **only for read access**.
>  The secondary database(s) are all available for read access.

They might sound like they're the same, but the "Yes" means that people can connect even if they don't specify ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in their connection string. This can be useful for legacy applications where the connection string can't be modified.

It's up to you, though, to make sure that the app doesn't try to do any writes. If it does, those queries will simply fail.

Read-intent only is a safer alternative when you know your apps have all been modified with ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in their connection string. That way, if an app accidentally tries to connect to the wrong place, you know it'll fail right at connection time and choose another replica immediately - rather than trying to start transactions that fail.

Comment: Thanks O (Oreo) and BO (Brent Ozar); that helps and is useful info. This is now answered and can be closed with an up vote.

Comment: @Prashant you're welcome. To indicate that the answer is accepted, click the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: Nice additional info Brent! I think DBA StackExchange has a policy for new-ish users, where you can only mark something as an answer after 2 days of the question going up.